# Wordpress pagination with wp_query_columns

Tags: pagination, columns

I'm using the code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9308/how-to-split-a-loop-into-multiple-columns) to split my loop up in to columns. The columns work. I have 7 posts in the databese and showposts set to 6. I cannot get nextpage link to show? I have a $paged variable in my $args array I have set number of posts per page to 5 in admin/reading. Full loop below. Many thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
'showposts' => 6,
'&paged=' => $paged,
'tax_query' => array(
    array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('post-format-audio')

        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);?>
<?php foreach(new WP_Query_Columns($the_query, 3) as $column_count) : ?>
    <ul class="sc-track-list fourteen columns alpha">
        <?php while ($column_count--) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="sc-track">
            <div class="sc-player">
                     <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_audio_embed' , true); ?>"></a></h1><!--title-->
                     </div>
        <div class="meta"> 
            <span class="entry-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span> 
            <a class="spch-bub-inside" href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">
                <span class="point"></span>  
                <em><?php comments_number('0', '1', '%'); ?></em>
            </a>                               
            <span class="entry-tag"><?php the_tags(' '); ?></span>                 

            <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
              data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
              data-via="jillowen"
              data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>"
              data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>
              </div>

        </li>


        <?php endwhile; ?>


    </ul>



<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using [the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). You should also use `get_posts` instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice. I'm using foreach as apposed to the loop.